# Looking up data in database from user

Tags: java, database, javabeans

I am trying to let a user lookup a football result, and the database displays that result from the database, but i keep getting this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLException: [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] Too few parameters. Expected 1.
```

This is my "useFootballBean.java" bean:

```
package results;
import results.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.sql.*;
public class UseFootballBean
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
            throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException
    {
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        String home;
        ResultsBean resultsBean = new ResultsBean();

        System.out.print("\nEnter Team: ");
        home = keyboard.next();
        home = resultsBean.getHome(home);
        if (home.equals(null))
            System.out.println(
                    "\n*** No such Team ***");
        else
        System.out.println("\nTeam " + home);
    }
```

}

This is my "resultsBean.java" bean

```
package results;
import java.sql.*;
public class ResultsBean
{
    private Connection connection;
    private Statement statement;
    private ResultSet results;
    public String getHome(String enter)
                throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException
    {
        String query;
        String team = null;
        connectAndCreateStatement();
        query = "SELECT * FROM Results WHERE homeTeam = "
            + enter;
        results = statement.executeQuery(query);
        if (results.next())
            team = results.getString("homeTeam");
        connection.close();
        return team;
    }

    private void connectAndCreateStatement()
                throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException
    {
        Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
        connection = DriverManager.getConnection(
                                  "jdbc:odbc:FootballData","","");
        statement = connection.createStatement();
}
}
```

Comment: Can you add Console message so we can give exact answer...

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to SQL injection attacks. Please use prepared statements instead!

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLException:[Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] Too few parameters. Expected 1.
 at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbc.createSQLException(JdbcOdbc.java:6956)
 at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbc.standardError(JdbcOdbc.java:7113)
 at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbc.SQLExecDirect(JdbcOdbc.java:3109)
 at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcStatement.execute(JdbcOdbcStatement.java:337)
 at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcStatement.executeQuery(JdbcOdbcStatement.java:252)
 at results.ResultsBean.getHome(ResultsBean.java:20)
 at results.UseFootballBean.main(UseFootballBean.java:18)

Comment: I think Below line help you..

query = "SELECT * FROM Results WHERE homeTeam = " + '"+ enter + "'";

Answer (score 2):

I think you are missing the single quotes required in where clause of query while comparing against a string value. Here you go:

```
where keyword_name='"+keyword_name+"'"

 query = "SELECT * FROM Results WHERE homeTeam = " + '"+ enter + "'";
```

Comment: What if the string entered by the user is `O'reilly`? What is it's `foo' of '1' = '1`?

Comment: In that case it will be good to use the Prepared statment and use your query as : SELECT * FROM Results WHERE homeTeam = ? And then simply call stmt.setString(1, enter)

Answer (score 1):

You are missing single quotation in your Sql Query

```
query = "SELECT * FROM Results WHERE homeTeam = '"
        + enter+"'";
```

OR with PreparedStatement to accept quotation

```
PreparedStatement stmt = null;
String sql;     
 ResultSet rows=null    

try {
sql = "select * from Results where homeTeam=?" 

stmt = theConn.prepareStatement(sql); 
stmt.setString(1, "Team with ' are permitted!"); 
rows = stmt.executeQuery(); 
stmt.close(); 
 }
 catch (Exception e){ 
 e.printStackTrace(); 
 }
 finally {  if (stmt != null) {
stmt.close();
}
```

Thanks

Comment: What if the string entered by the user is `O'reilly`? What is it's `foo' of '1' = '1`?

Comment: It's better to use Regex.. if you consider getting those type of values

Comment: No. It's better to use prepared statements. And you HAVE to consider those kinds of values, because a user could enter them and make your query fail.

Comment: @JBNizet.. Yup.. Answers edited with  a simple PreparedStatement examp.

Comment: executeUpdate() doesn't return a ResultSet, and must not be used to execute select queries.

Answer (score 1):

Since your query parameter is a string, you need to enclose it in quotes:

```
"SELECT * FROM Results WHERE homeTeam = '" + enter + "'";
```

However, this is still a bad approach, because it leaves you vulnerable to SQL injection (Remember [Bobby Tables](http://xkcd.com/327/)?), and will break if the user enters a team name containing quote characters (like `England's Greatest Team`). Therefore, you should use a `PreparedStatement` (see [Java tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html)).